# when adding new element to the end of array it changes using splice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, browser

When `$scope.event` reach BufferLimit i am removing first element from an array that will reduce `totalReceived` value than i am pushing new element outside if statement, but when i push new element i dont see that as last item in array ? I also use `slice` that froze my browser at bufferlimit with `shift` it is same as `slice`. I am looking for better solution because of high data volume ?

Ctrl.js

```
 //BufferLimit is 8MB totalReceived value is coming from other method

 $scope.event = [];
    function safelyAdd(element) {
        if (totalReceived > Bufferlimit && $scope.event.length) {

     $scope.event = $scope.event.splice(1); //delete first element in $scope.event

            totalReceived -= $scope.event[0].messageSize; //total message size minus deleted message size
            console.log('totalReceivedBytes', totalReceived);
            // $scope.event =[];//reset array if max size reached..
            console.log('$scope.event', $scope.event)
        }
        console.log('$scope.event.length', $scope.event.length);

            $scope.event.push(element); //then push new item..

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In your code line# 4, dont assign spliced array to same array.Just splice it
```

as below
     $scope.event.splice(1); //delete first element in $scope.event

Comment: so just create new array object `var temp = $scope.event.splice(1);`

Comment: oh you said just splice it

Comment: but i see `$scope.event.length` kept growing with new messages even we `splice` first element, that is actual purpose to reduce load on browser

Comment: After splicing one element, again you are adding another element(ie. after if block). add else block to control, if your requirement satisfies.

Comment: This line should be before splice,                                                           totalReceived -= $scope.event[0].messageSize;

Comment: I dont have access to chat..sorry

Comment: Have you tried this? This line should be before splice, totalReceived -= $scope.event[0].messageSize; (as you are trying to reduce the size of element after you are splicing the element.)

Comment: but at some point `$scope,event.length` should not increase when it reaches Bufferlimit lets say if i haev 10 messages at Bufferlimit it should splice 1 and add new as 10